# Are bitwise operators supported in regular shell /bin/sh (not bash)

Tags: shell, unix, sh, solaris, bitwise-operators

I am getting errors in using bitwise & operators in /bin/sh.  I can make it work in bash, but the script which will execute the code starts in regular shell, so I need to make it work in plain regular shell. I need to simply check if a certain bit is set e.g. 7th bit

Following code work in bash, but not in /bin/sh

```
#!/bin/bash
y=93
if [ $((($y & 0x40) != 0)) ]; then
  echo bit 7 is set
fi
```

I tried above in /bin/sh by removing arithmatic expansion

```
#!/bin/sh
y=93
val=`expr $y & 0x40`
if [ $val != 0 ]; then
   echo worked 1
fi
```

Can someone suggest how bitwise operator can be use in plain regular shell?

Comment: `sh` does not support bit shift operations.

Comment: NB: "bit 7" is usually considered the MSB, e.g. the one with mask `0x80`, with "bit 0" being the LSB

Comment: `/bin/sh` can be either POSIX sh (early 1990s standard), or Bourne shell (1970s-era implementation). On Solaris in particular, both of those have been present in modern times (with the former usually in `/usr/xpg/bin` if the latter is in `/bin`); `$(( ))` only exists at all in the former. Do you know which you have?

Comment: ...if you want to determine that experimentally, check the output of `echo hello ^ cat`; if it's `hello`, you're running Bourne shell; if it's `hello ^ cat`, you're running POSIX sh.

Comment: BTW, POSIX `expr` supports `&`, but it's defined by POSIX as a boolean-logic operator, not a bitwise operator. You'd need to escape it for it to work even in that way: `expr "$i" '&' 64`; the unescaped `&` in your original code tells the shell to put everything to the left of it into its own command running in the background (and then tries to parse the content on the right as another separate command, so it's running `0x40` as a command, and capturing that command's output into the variable named `val`... hence your original code's failure).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -  Thanks for clarifying difference between POSIX and Bourne. Since it printed 'hello', so I have Bourne shell.

Comment: Ahh -- there's our answer, then. BTW, on Solaris, using `#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` as your shebang is likely to give you POSIX sh, if you wanted the newer syntax to be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use division and modulo operations to check for a particular bit:

```
if [ `expr \( $y / 64 \) % 2` -eq 1 ]; then
  echo bit 6 is set
fi
```

Comment: `==` is not guaranteed by POSIX sh to be supported in `[`, nor was it supported in pre-POSIX implementations of `[`. If you're trying to be compatible, use `=` (for a string comparison) or `-eq` (for a numeric comparison).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, I don't actually have an old non-bash /bin/sh to test with

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think this should now work on any version of `sh`

Comment: I think so too. I kinda' hate the anachronisms (and am waiting for the OP's confirmation that they really are on pre-POSIX Bourne before lending my upvote to something that uses them), but can't find any correctness faults (except maybe for lack of double quotes around the command substitution, and that's nitpicking -- it'd only create a reachable bug if your `expr` failed, or if `IFS` contained `0` or `1`) as-edited.

Comment: @Alnitak conversion to division and modulo seems making it compatible to shell I have. Arithmatic expansion can only be used in limited shells. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're using the string returned by your arithmetic expansion, and not the exit code.  You probably should do the test for equal to `0` on the outside like

```
if [ "$((y & 0x40))" -ne 0 ]; then
```

otherwise `$(((y & 0x40) != 0))` is returning a string, and it will always be non-empty so the truth test will always pass.

Comment: POSIX specifies `&` in [the set of arithmetic operations referred to by reference in the POSIX sh standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap01.html#tag_01_07_02_01), so if the OP is dealing with POSIX sh rather than Bourne, this should indeed work.

Comment: ...unfortunately, Solaris has shipped both in recent decades, so we need clarification from the OP on exactly which implementation they're running to know with certainty whether this answer applies.

Comment: (I was *almost* about to say that it'd be safer to switch the constant from hex to decimal, but looking closely at the POSIX sh arithmetic standard, hex constants are required behavior for POSIX sh as well, so we really are in a good place here unless the OP is using Bourne).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy looks like the OP has a plain old Bourne Shell, and not POSIX

Comment: @Alnitak, yup, I saw that earlier this morning, and my promised upvote took place then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alnitak answer, I'd do:

```
if expr \( $y / 128 \) % 2 > /dev/null; then
  echo bit 7 is set
fi
```

It's just a little more concise.

Notice that: 2^7=128